# SQL QUERY regarding single row as output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a query in which it only returns only one output row based on the values in a column.
What I need is

Table A has values

```
  A
 ----|----
   1 |
   2 |
   3 |

required output
  A
 ----
 yes
```

so I need a query in which if table a has 3 in its column then the output I need to get is yes or else no.
my code:-

```
WITH
number_tb AS (select * from t1),
out_put as (select case when a = 3 then 'yes' else 'no' end a_case from number_tb)
select * from out_put

output:-
a_case
-----
no
no
yes
```

I only need single row output. if 3 is present then yes or no, I don't need it for each row.
Is it possible to do so??

Comment: Please don't tag spam. PL/SQL is related to Oracle and that, MySQL, and SQL Server are *not* PostgreSQL.

Comment: "PostgreSQL or SQL" makes no sense. SQL is a query language used by all relational databases - including PostgreSQL

Comment: Unless you have a bad design with too many tables, you probably want something more like `select Id, case when min(A) filter (where A = 3) = 3 then 'yes' else 'no' end from T group by Id`. This applies to groups rather than whole tables.

Answer (score 1):

If a proper boolean true/false value is also acceptable, you can use

```
select exists (select * from t1 where a = 3) as a;
```

If you want a string with `yes/no` instead you can use a CASE expression to turn the boolean value into a string.

```
select case 
          when exists (select * from t1 where a = 3) then 'Yes'
          else 'No'
        end as a;
```